# Is it possible to filter Twilio status emails to USA only, so I don't receive status emails about countries where we are not presently operating

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to filter Twilio status emails to USA only, so I don't receive status emails about countries where we are not presently operating?

We receive Twilio status emails for many countries that are presently irrelevant to our business operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can read the support article [Checking Twilio Service and API Status with the Status Page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013353193-Checking-Twilio-Service-and-API-Status-with-the-Status-Page) for details on how to sign up and select only carrier notifications for only specific areas of the world.

The tl;dr is go to status.twilio.com, subscribe to updates and on the subscription page, find the Carrier Network section to select only the carriers in North America.